# Show current position in disassembly with stepi command in GDB

Tags: assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering, disassembly, binary-bomb

I have a code which is already compiled and I don't have the libraries to compile it myself again.

When I look into it with GDB, set a breakpoint and use the `stepi` (aka `si`) or `nexti` command, usually I get the next line of assembly code shown and can walk myself forward. Here however I just get the notification that I went to the next line in a given function, without showing me the next line of code.

So basically after every step I have to disassemble the function again to look where I am. How can I change that and why is that happening?

[image: Picture for reference]

Comment: That's normal if you don't have source. You can switch to `layout asm` or set up a `display/i $pc` or similar.

Comment: I have the source file, I just miss a couple of includes

Comment: You have the C source for a binary bomb lab?  Those are normally given as asm reverse-engineering challenges.

Comment: Yes, it is :D I am studying at the moment and whe have to figure out how the bomb isnt going to explode

Answer (score 1):

> So basicly after every step I have to disassemble the function again to look where I am. How can I change that and why is that happening ?

You can use `display/i $pc` to automatically show you the next instruction or `display/4i $pc` to show the next 4.

Or you could switch to TUI with `layout asm`.

Comment: I usually use `layout reg` / `layout next`.  (In older GDB versions, `layout reg` was disassembly + register panes.  A few years ago it changed or broke or something and is source + register panes.  `layout n` cycles to the next layout after `layout reg`, which is registers + disassembly.  I don't know a name for that layout, and `layout reg` / `layout next` in `.gdbinit` doesn't work so I have to do the `layout n` part manually.)